# Select last N rows SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am currently working with Big Data. I am importing data into a table  which is about 200 million records per import. I want to see how many records are loaded in for the current import. But currently my script is running through 1 billion records first to finally count the last imported data.

```
SELECT Datum, COUNT(Datum) AS recCount
FROM   PF161DailyAggregates
GROUP BY Datum
```

That is my current code which shows the amount of rows per Date 
I can make the code that it only shows the current import job but it will still go through all the other records.

Currently this query takes about an hour. How can I make this fast to only count the last N rows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Auto tag, removed now

Comment: What about `select top n ... from ... order by .. desc `

Comment: That's not Big Data, it's a SQL problem with a large table. First, ensure `Datum` is indexed. Assuming an import only adds later dates, select the max date before importing, then use it to filter the table with a `WHERE`. Consider compression, partitioning and/or columnstore indexes to improve speed, they can result in significantly better performance.

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot get some "last" data in SQL easily. Try to change your criteria or sorting to query for the "first" data. Then you can limit the result effectively.

Comment: Why don't you just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Datum>=@previousMaxDatum`?

Answer (score 0):

this will restrict result to 100 rows and you can get last rows by giving order by clause `desc`

```
SELECT Datum, COUNT(Datum) AS recCount
FROM   PF161DailyAggregates
GROUP BY Datum
order by datum desc
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: and if I were to want to skip the first N rows it would be: order by datum OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT N ROWS ONLY; 

correct?

Comment: Sorry, thats not helping. OFFSET will work on the end result set and will NOT help reducing the number of rows considered to do the order, group and count! OFFSET will ALSO NOT help reducing computation time because all it does is shorten the result set that is returned to the client AFTER it was determined!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a hard one. I think as long as you want to find out the last records AFTER the import, you are required to use some ordering on the Datum column. You can try various tricks there but as long as this column does not have an index, you will be lost, since any ordering requires a full table scan. So my first suggestion is to make an index on that column, then you can use any technique that restricts your result to the last date like:

```
select top 1 Datum, count(Datum)
from PF161DailyAggregates
group by Datum
order by Datum desc
```

or

```
select count(*)
from PF161DailyAggregates
where Datum = (select top 1 Datum
               from PF161DailyAggregates
               order by Datum desc)
```

Another idea would be to break out of the box and make the import job write the number of records per Datum in a seperate table each time it runs. That would be much cheaper.

Comment: No need for TOP. MAX(Datum) will return the latest date. As for the separate table - you'd still have to use the same statement as the OP used to create that table.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to find count on single table,

```
SELECT T.name AS [TABLE NAME], 
       I.rows AS [ROWCOUNT] 
FROM   sys.tables AS T 
       INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes AS I 
               ON T.object_id = I.id 
                  AND I.indid < 2 
where T.name ='PF161DailyAggregates'
ORDER  BY I.rows DESC
```

Alternatively,

you can create one identity column.
Before insert find max id== easy and fast
then after insert find SCOPE_IDENTITY() in variable.
then subtract these two .

If table already contain one rownumber type in sequence then
also you can use same technique using First_Value in sql server 2012